# Comparing two SQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am looking to filter results by date, which I gotten to work just fine. Now I'm trying to have the database return values based on  each employee in that filtered period. Example in the employee table:

```
ID        Hourly
```

then in the data table

```
ID        Hours
```

So I was trying for if the IDs match then look up how much the hourly and hours would total out to. Here's what I have thus far.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("MY_INFO.com","USER","*********","DB_NAME");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$data = mysqli_query($con,"Select * FROM employees
Select * FROM data
SELECT t1 *, t2.*
From employees t1
INNER JOIN data t2 on t1.id = t2.id
'");

  while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
  echo $data['id'] . " " . $data['id'];
  echo "<br>";
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM friends
WHERE date >'2014-09-1' and date < '2014-9-30'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['id'];
  echo "<br>";
```

I'm trying to filter by date, and then match IDs from both tables so if an id equals an id from the other table then it could return an hourly wage. So if employee id: 1 had an hourly wage of $20 / hr and worked 2 hours then I could get it to return $40. The tables would have in them:

```
Employee: 
ID          $/hr 
1            20
Data: 
ID          Hours
1           2
```

Comment: Your tables look like they need a join. But first, would you clarify your table names? So far I see you have 'employee', 'data' (from your description) and 'volunteers', 'hours' (from your code). I suspect in reality you have two names for two tables - if so, please edit your question to switch to one set of names.

Comment: What you have there is a cross join which will return a cartesian product of the two tables. Not likely what you are looking for. You should also get in the habit of naming the columns you want returned instead of *.

Comment: @SeanLange but would I use both columns in each table as I'm comparing? Should as should use a join function I would only need 1 column?

Comment: You're also likely missing data for September 30th, since you have date < '2014-09-30' you likely want to move that date to Oct-1 to get all of September.

Comment: @halfer I have altered my names for tables so they should match up now. How would you recommend implementing the join function?

Comment: @AdamWenger Ah! Thanks for catching that!

Comment: They don't match up, still. How many tables do you have? I see three: 'data', 'hours', 'employee'.  Your query mentions a column of 'date' but I don't know what table that is in. Please add _all_ your tables and their columns into your question.

Comment: You need to do some research on joins. This is fundamental to being able to work with relational data. It seems you don't understand the concept yet. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

Comment: I just realized this is no longer tagged with sql server. The link I posted is still relevant but the syntax is sql server.

Comment: @SeanLange I updated the code now using an inner join. I would assume that would be the way to go? Else I was considering a left join however I need values from both sides. I used the the link you provided earlier. Thank you, I think that got me on a better track.

Comment: it would help to know what your original data looks like, structure and data, and what the expected result is. As it is, you have sent 3 separate queries to the server, doesnt make much sense.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu I updated the question to include sample data.